# "Home is not defined" error using React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Here's my code for my App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Education from './contents/Education';

function App() {  return (

    <Router>
    {/* route navbar */}
    <div className="App">

    <Navbar />

    {/* route 2 home */}
    <Route exact path="/Home">

    < Home />

    </Route>

    {/* Route for About.js contents */}

    <Route path="/About">

    < About />

    </Route>

     {/* route to widecard */}

     <Route path="/Education">

     <Education />

     </Route>

    </div>

    </Router>

    )
}

export default App;
```

When I run npm start in my terminal I get this error:

```
./src/App.js
Line 18:7:  'Home' is not defined   react/jsx-no-undef
Line 26:7:  'About' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef
```

I have a Home.js and an About.js... I'm still learning react so if this seems like a simple fix I'm sorry in advance! Please let me know if any more information needs to be provided.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You never import `Home` or `About`, so your code can't access it.

Comment: I added import with source: `import Home from 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src\Content\Home.js'` and now receive this error : `Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:UsersAlexportjssrcContentAbout.js' in 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src'`

Answer (score 1):

You don't import `Home` or `About` at the top of the file. IF you import those in, I think you'll be good to go.

Also `< Home />` shouldn't have a space between the open bracket and the name. Should be `<Home />`.

Comment: I added import with source: `import Home from 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src\Content\Home.js'` and now receive this error : `Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:UsersAlexportjssrcContentAbout.js' in 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the componant (Home and About) so you can use then.

Home.js and About.js should contain an [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) , and App.js should contain

```
import Home from 'path/to/Home/Home' //(you dont need to write the .js)
```

And same with About

Comment: I added import with source: `import Home from 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src\Content\Home.js'` and now receive this error : `Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:UsersAlexportjssrcContentAbout.js' in 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src'`

Comment: You need to use / and not \  :
`import Home from 'C:/Users/Alex/portjs/src/Content/Home.js' ` 
And you dont need the full path, you can use the relative path  `./Content/Home`

Answer (score 0):

As with using any component it must first be exported then imported. As it appears that the later was overlooked in your code.

```
import About from '..relative path to -> /About'  
import Home from '..relative path to -> /Home'
```

Comment: I added import with source: `import Home from 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src\Content\Home.js'` and now receive this error : `Module not found: Can't resolve 'C:UsersAlexportjssrcContentAbout.js' in 'C:\Users\Alex\portjs\src'`

Answer (score 0):

When you import something from other modules be sure to mention that function .I assume you know this fact but these mistakes can happen

i.e
import Home from "./pages/home/Home"

Comment: Please format code.